# C++-Is it obvious?

Tags: c++

I am supposed to be converting a permutation program into an 8 of queens program. The program is supposed to put a queen down in the first row, then in the second row it is supposed to place down a queen that is not in direct view of the prior queen. At the end, if 8 queens cannot be placed, the program shall pick up the previous queen and recalculate.

The output for this program is as follows.

Executing the program....

```
$demo 
Q _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ Q 
_ _ _ _ _ _ Q _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ Q 
_ _ _ _ _ _ Q _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ Q 
_ _ _ _ _ _ Q _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ Q
```

(It's 8x8)

Clearly those last two rows are in direct sight of eachother, and i'm unsure of where i should start by fixing this, if I could get input that would be great, hopefully it isn't something obvious!

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;

char BOARD[8][8];

void clearBoard();
void attempt(int n, int row, int column);
void placeQueen(int row, int column);
void removeQueen(int row, int column);
bool currentPathSuccess(int n, int row, int column);
bool currentPathStillViable(int row, int column);
void printBoard(int n);


int main()
{
    int n = 8;
    clearBoard();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            attempt(n, i, j);
        }
    }
    printBoard(n);
    return 0;
}//end Main

void clearBoard()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            BOARD[i][j] = '_';
        }
    }   
}//end clearBoard Function

void attempt(int n, int row, int column)
{
    placeQueen(row, column);

    if(currentPathSuccess(n, row, column))
        {printBoard(n);}
        else
    currentPathStillViable(row, column);
}// end attempt Function

void placeQueen(int row, int column)
{
    BOARD[row][column] = 'Q';
}
void removeQueen(int row, int column)
{
    BOARD[row][column] = '_';
}//end placeQueen Function

bool currentPathSuccess(int n, int row, int column)    //Flag
{
    bool success = true;

    if((n > column)||(n > row))
       { 
           success = false;
       }
    return success;
}//end currentPathSuccess Function

bool currentPathStillViable(int row, int column)    //Flag
 {
    bool viable = true;
    int flag = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        if(BOARD[row][x] == 'Q')
        {
             flag++;
        }
    }
    if(flag > 1)
    {
        removeQueen(row, column);
        placeQueen(row + 1, column);
    }
    return viable;
}// end currentPathStillViable

void printBoard(int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << BOARD[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}//end printBoard Function
```

Comment: I think you're confusing rows with columns. Especially in your `currentPathStillViable()` method.

Comment: bool currentPathStillViable(int row, int column) //Flag
    {
        bool viable = true;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if(BOARD[row][column] == 'Q')
            {
                 i++;
            }
        }
        if(i > 1)
        {
            removeQueen(row, column);
            placeQueen(row + 1, column);
        }
        return viable;
    }                                                                         I updated it to this, to kind of fix the row/column confusion and now all it does it place down a lot of Qs

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your comment. =/

Comment: I fixed it sorry, I just posted  what I changed the current path to, and the output is an 8x8 of Q's :s it looks like you can't do code blocks in comments :(

Comment: So why not test both row && column instead of testing one or neither?

Comment: it's still not function when I have it test one, was there any other issues besides the row testing that could be causing this?